# How to find a function $f$ that satisfies the equation $f(x)=af(x-1)+b(f(x-1)^2)$

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

How to find a function $f$ that satisfies the recurrence   relation:

$f(1)=k$

$f(x)=af(x-1)+b(f(x-1))^2$
for $x\ge 2$.

Where $x$ is a member of the set of positive integers, $f$ is a member of the set of real numbers and $a=0.5, b=0.25, k=0.25$

There’s probably more than one function $f$ that satisfies the equation. So is there like a general form for all $f$ that do so?

Comment: Please post some of your own work on this question. Also note that this is a "sequence" - which of course still can be called a "function".

Comment: @WhatsUpActually that’s the problem. I’m not a mathematician and I arrived at this problem while dealing with an entirely different problem. I have absolutely no idea what to do here. I know it’s a sequence. I am particularly interested in knowing the sum of the sequence. But I need to know what the sequence is first.

Comment: +¿Conditions for $a,b,k$?

Comment: @Piquito I’ve updated the question

Comment: If you need only the limiting behavior of $f$, then you may not need to compute a closed form for $f(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar I suppose you’re right. I could just keep summing the values up to a large enough x and use the value of sum that is precise enough for me.

Comment: $f(x)$ converges to $0$.  Maybe you need the rate of convergence?

Comment: @GEdgar. Yes $f(x)$ converges to zero. I was looking for the limit of the summation of $f(x)$ as x approaches infinity. In other words I’m looking for the limit of “$f(1) + f(2) + f(3)+..........$” as x approaches infinity.

Comment: It seems to be $0.294997277999181255826933308$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130910/discussion-between-david-okogbenin-and-gedgar).

Answer (score 3):

This is **iteration** of the quadratic function $\phi(z) = az+bz^2$.  Then
$$
f(n) = \phi\big(\phi\big(\dots \phi(k)\big)\big)
$$
where the number of $\phi$s is $n$.

Mandelbrot (among others) studied this question.  Any such iteration is equivalent to another iteration of the form $\psi(z) = z^2+c$ for some $c$.  A "closed form" is known for the answer only when $c=0$ or $c=-2$.

In your case, $a=1/2, b=1/4$, we compute $c=3/16$, so there is no simple closed form.

Comment: Is it proven that there is no simple closed form? Or is it the case that a simple closed form is not known?

Comment: The precise type of "closed form" that exists only for $c=0,-2$ is described by Eremenko, page 663, in: L. Rubel, "Some research problems about algebraic differential equations, II" *Ill. J. Math.* **36** (1992) 659--680.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first let's sort out the terminology confusion here. A *function* is a mathematical object which associates each value in a specified *domain* to a value in a *codomain*.

For instance, $g(x)=x^2$ on the domain $\mathbb{R}$, all real numbers, is a function. So is the function $h$ on the domain of positive integers described by the process "if the input is less than $10$, add $8$ to it; otherwise triple the number and subtract $154$".

The function you have given has domain "positive integers" and codomain "real numbers". We can write that as $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if we like.

You have then given a description of how the function maps each input to an output. The recurrence relation uniquely defines each input-output pair: for instance

$$ f(1)=k=0.25\\ f(2)=af(1)+bf(1)^2=0.5\times 0.25+0.25\times 0.25^2=0.140625\\f(3)=af(2)+bf(2)^2=0.07525634765625$$

and so on. The method of calculating $f(100)$ - by calculating $f(n)$ from $n=1$ upwards - is clear. In fact, it's also clear that it doesn't matter what the values of $a,b,k$ are: we could delay the choice of values for them and find expressions for $f(n)$ in terms of $a,b,k$: $f(2)=bk^2+ak$, $f(3)=b^3k^4+2ab^2k^3+a(a+1)bk^2+a^2k$.

What I gather you are asking for is a simpler way to calculate the values of the function, and moreover a way to calculate the sum of the values.

Unfortunately, the particular type of recurrence you have is a [quadratic map](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html) and it is not, in general, easy to find a closed-form expression for it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the terminology. I asked the question because I am interested in the sum of the first n terms of the function. I observed that it seems the summation of the function has a limit. If there is no simpler way to express the function. Is there a way for me to get the limit of its sum?

Comment: I can see no better way than by calculating the sum up to a large enough value that you can convince yourself that the limit is accurate to the precision you need for it.

Answer (score -2):

COMMENT.-$$f(2)=ak+bk^2\\f(x-1)=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4bf(x)}}{2b}\\f(1)=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b(ak+bk^2)}}{2b}=\frac{-a\pm(2bk+a)}{2b}=k$$
We must use negative sign (positive one gives nothing) so we have
$$\boxed{a=-2bk}$$ It follows $$f(2)=\frac{-a^2}{2b}\\f(3)= \frac{a^4-2a^2}{2b}\\.......\\.......$$